# APIv4 Histogram - can't sort

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to fetch **5 days histogram** from google analytics via APIv4, where each bucket is 1 day

This is the query that i'm trying to implement and it works fine when running via Query builder

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "810020000",
      "filtersExpression": "ga:pagePath=@mypage",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "5daysAgo",
          "endDate": "today"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:entranceRate"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:nthDay",
          "histogramBuckets": [
            "0",
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "orderBys": [
        {
          "fieldName": "ga:nthDay",
          "orderType": "HISTOGRAM_BUCKET",
          "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**however** when i try to run the same query through JAVA (APIv4) i only get a single result (if im not adding sortBy)
and an error below if I add sort

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Sort key ga:nthDay is not a dimension or metric in this query.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Sort key ga:nthDay is not a dimension or metric in this query.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

This is the java code

```
Integer uniquePageviews = analyticsApi.getUniquePageViewsHistogramDaily("5daysAgo", "today", "ga:uniquePageviews");

public Integer getUniquePageViewsHistogramDaily(String startDayPhrase, String endDayPhrase, String gaMetricsPhrase) throws IOException {
            DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
            dateRange.setStartDate(startDayPhrase);
            dateRange.setEndDate(endDayPhrase);
            List<DateRange> dateRanges = new ArrayList<>();
            dateRanges.add(dateRange);

            Metric metric = new Metric();
            metric.setExpression(gaMetricsPhrase);
            List<Metric> metrics = new ArrayList<>();
            metrics.add(metric);

        //TODO caclulate dynamically
        List<Long> histogramBuckets = new ArrayList<>();
        histogramBuckets.add(0L);
        histogramBuckets.add(1L);
        histogramBuckets.add(2L);
        histogramBuckets.add(3L);
        histogramBuckets.add(4L);

        List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
        Dimension histogram = new Dimension();
        histogram.setName("ga:nthDay");
        histogram.setHistogramBuckets(histogramBuckets);


        List<OrderBy> orderBys = new ArrayList<>();
        OrderBy orderByDay = new OrderBy();
        orderByDay.setFieldName("ga:nthDay");
        orderByDay.setOrderType("HISTOGRAM_BUCKET");
        orderByDay.setSortOrder("ASCENDING");

        orderBys.add(orderByDay);

        return getUniquePageViewsHistogramDaily(dateRanges, metrics, dimensions, "ga:pagePath=@myaccount",orderBys);
    }

    private Integer getUniquePageViewsHistogramDaily(List<DateRange> dateRangeList,
                                                     List<Metric> metrics,
                                                     List<Dimension> dimensions,
                                                     String filterExpression,
                                                     List<OrderBy> orderBys) throws IOException {

        ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
                .setViewId(getViewId())
                .setDateRanges(dateRangeList)
                .setDimensions(dimensions)
                .setMetrics(metrics)
                .setFiltersExpression(filterExpression)
                .setOrderBys(orderBys);

        ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        requests.add(request);

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest().setReportRequests(requests);
        // Call the batchGet method.
        GetReportsResponse response = analyticsBuilder.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();


        return Integer.valueOf(response.getReports().get(0).getData().getTotals().get(0).getValues().get(0));
    }
```

How can i get a normal 5 days histogram via Java?

Comment: This one https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/#results

Comment: Sounds weird to me since it states the following in the bottom of the page:

Comment: The Request Composer uses the Embed API's ViewSelector to select the user's view. It also uses the Metadata API to populate the items in the dimensions and metrics dropdowns. Lastly, it uses the Analytics Reporting API v4 to make the request.

Comment: What do you mean? It doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
Thanks to Intellij I've found the issue
Appears that ive forgot to add the histogram dimension to dimensions list

```
dimensions.add(histogram);
```

Now all is working as expected 
Thank you!

Comment: Next time try a HTTP proxy first to see what goes over the "line".

Comment: will do. Thank you!